# How to split parsed String data without special characters?

Tags: java, android, parsing, split, substring

I parsed this data from Wikipedia and trying to get only characters from here. But the result comes with `\n*` in the front of data.

> "*": "=== 고양이의  종류 ===\n* [[시암고양이]]\n* [[페르시안 네브스카야]]\n* [[페르시안]]\n*
>   [[노르웨이지언 포레스트]]\n* [[터키시 앙고라]]\n* [[아메리칸 숏헤어]]\n* [[브리티시 숏헤어]]\n*
>   [[러시안블루]]\n* [[뱅갈]]\n* [[메인쿤]]\n* [[랙돌]]\n* [[히말라얀]]\n* [[재패니즈
>   밥테일]]\n* [[오리엔탈 숏헤어]]\n* [[피터볼드]]\n* [[스코티시 폴드]]\n* 스코티시 스트레이트\n*
>   [[하일랜드 폴드]]\n* [[시베리안 포레스트]]\n* [[터키시 반]]\n* [[코리안 쇼트헤어]]\n*
>   [[올블랙]]\n* [[사바나캣]]\n* [[쿠나]]\n* [[아비시니안]]\n* 먼치킨"

This is my code.

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("https://ko.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=20&titles=%EA%B3%A0%EC%96%91%EC%9D%B4&format=json");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

        while(true){
            String data = reader.readLine();
            if(data == null) break;
            result += data;
        }
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject query = (JSONObject) obj.get("query");
        JSONObject pages = (JSONObject) query.get("pages");
        JSONObject pageid = (JSONObject) pages.get("93349");
        JSONArray revisions = (JSONArray) pageid.get("revisions");
        String catcat = String.valueOf(revisions);
        String star = "\n*";
        catcat = catcat.replaceAll("\\[\\[","").replaceAll("\\]\\]",",").replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "").replaceAll(star,"");
        String[] catcategory = catcat.split(",");


      for (int i = 0; i<catcategory.length;i++){
          list.add(catcategory[i]);

      }






    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Result for this looks like

> \n*시암고양이
>
>   \n*페르시안

and I want to remove `\n*`.

Comment: Use `text.replaceAll("\n*", " ");`

Comment: Add one more \ in `String star = "\\n\*";`

Comment: I've tried. it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `.replace("\\n", "")`. If a backslash plus 'n' appears, one would need 4 backslashes in regex to represent a single backslash (`replaceAll`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to split parsed String data without special characters?

Try this piece of code, It's removed **\n*** , Then you can add **_result_word** to your list.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < catcategory.length; i++) {
            try {
                String _result_word = catcategory[i].replaceFirst("\\\\n", "").replace("*", "");
                //String _result_word=catcategory[i].replaceFirst("\\\\n", "").replace("*", "").replaceFirst("\\\\n", "").replace("*", "");
                System.out.println("" + _result_word);
                list.add(_result_word);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Special Exception occurred at index : i = " + i);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also, You can use : String _result_word=catcategory[i].replaceFirst("\\\\n", "").replace("*", "").replaceFirst("\\\\n", "").replace("*", "");

Comment: Thanks!! This worked! If you can, can you explain how this worked?

Answer (score 0):

Everything correct except one line where you need escape asterisk character and escape slash character

```
String star = "\\\\n\\*";
str.replaceAll(star, "");
```

Comment: @Sanoop no, this is correct answer. Topicstarter code works correct with my fix